# Insert different Picture object after each row print in Fast Report

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, fastreport, firemonkey-fm2

I am developing an application in Firemonkey (Delphi XE5) where I am using Fast report 4 for printing data. I am using TFrxUserDataSet to keep data and to print this, I am using MasterData band in fast report.

Now, I also need to print TBitamp with each row, so here the bitmap for each record will be different.

Does any body has any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Is this bitmap part of your record or loaded from an external file?

Comment: This is loaded from some file, but at runtime. i think it is not possible to store image or TBitmap in TFrxUserDataSet's field.

Comment: @PadamJain you might not be able to store an image or TBitmap in the TFrxUserDataSet's field but you could store the filename assuming all images are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Нou can load an external image file into a picture control in your report.  I'm doing this with a script that is part of the report itself using the OnBeforePrint event as follows:

```
PROCEDURE Data2OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
VAR
  lFN               : STRING;
  lFP               : STRING;
BEGIN
  // Use the filename as found in the Media dataset fields
  lFP := Trim(< Media."ImagePath">);    // Images folder below Image Root Path
  lFN := Trim(< Media."FileName1">);    // Actual Image File Name

  WITH Picture2 DO BEGIN

    // NB: There is no checking in this example, it may be useful to do a 
    //     couple of checks before trying to load the image, especially if 
    //     the data is user entered
    LoadFromFile(ImageRootPath + IncludeTrailingSlash(lFP) + lFN);

    // Do whatever manipulations you want to with the loaded image...
    AutoSize := False;
    Width := 1620;
    Height := 1080;
    Top := 0;
    Left := (1920 - Width) / 2;

    HightQuality := True;    // Note the typo in the property name... HighQuality?
    KeepAspectRatio := True;
    Transparent := True;
    Stretched := NOT Picture3.AutoSize;
  END;
END;
```

Note that I have added a few user functions like ImageRootPath IncludeTrailingSlash() to make the script easier.  You could do similar to check for a valid file prior to attempting to load to avoid exceptions.

My devt environment is Delphi XE5 with FastReport FMX and it works just fine.  I am in the midst of moving to XE6 and FR FMX 2, but am pretty sure this will work fine.